# How to add nginx configurator group?

Tags: nginx, configuration, user-management, user-permissions, ubuntu-20.04

I want o create a user group that has permissions to create/edit/view nginx configs without sudo permissions, but I heve no idea how.

Creating a normal user group and setting owner:group to same-owner:configurator-group for the nginx configs location, the user can edit and view but creating a file sets the new file owner and group to the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=windows-creating-managing-groups-linux) - provides an overview of managing user groups and file permissions on an Ubuntu system.

Create the user group using the groupadd command:

```
sudo groupadd configurator
```

Add the users who should be members of the configurator group using the usermod command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G configurator [username]
```

Change the ownership and permissions of the Nginx configuration files to allow the configurator group to read and write to the files:

```
sudo chown root:configurator /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
sudo chmod 640 /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
```

you may want to prevent members of the configurator group from creating new files in the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory. To do this, you can set the sticky bit on the directory:

```
sudo chmod +t /etc/nginx/conf.d
```